# Profiling Spring application to minimize startup-time

Tags: java, spring, profiling

I have a large Spring application that is not properly divided into profiles. I would like to break bean configs so irrelevant beans taking long time to load are replace with mocks.

How can I do profiling of Spring application to find out beans causing startup to be slow? Memory usage will not reflect long waiting block HTTP requests that can contribute to the lags.

Thanks,
Witold

Answer (score 0):

You can profile using `jvisualvm`
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/intro.html
There is a VisualVM Startup Profiler Plugin available here:
https://visualvm.github.io/startupprofiler.html

An other approach could be to use `spring-startup-analysis` if you are able to change the codebase. (This seems to provide exactly what you are looking for)

https://github.com/lwaddicor/spring-startup-analysis